# If the gradient cannot be obtained, is there a similar way working as gradient descend?

Tags: gradient-descent

A function `f` has inputs as a set of parameters and output as the accuracy. The gradient of `f` cannot be obtained, is there a similar way working as gradient descend, such as finite difference?

Comment: If you can evaluate a function, you can always get an estimate of its gradient by taking differences at neighboring points. Which is essentially what finite differences are all about.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really true that you cannot obtain the gradient for accuracy. There is a well defined gradient for accuracy wrt. parameters. The problem is it is **equal to 0** almost everywhere. So any approximation technique (such as sampling, finite differences) will also work, and give you 0 gradient. There are many gradient-free optimisations, but by their very nature they are orders of magnitude less efficient, and often called "meta optimisers", such as basin hooping, simulated annealing, genetic algorithms, etc.